# Altering the prompt

Tags: bash, paths

Ok, so i am trying to create an alias, that would allow me to set the current directory in the terminal, the base directory to be displayed in prompt. Let's assume the alias is named *basedir*

For instance:

```
andrepadez@theLookingGlass:~$ cd Shared  
andrepadez@theLookingGlass:~/Shared$ cd development/  
andrepadez@theLookingGlass:~/Shared/development$ cd nodejs/
```

right now, i would run that alias and i would get the following prompt:

```
andrepadez@theLookingGlass:~/Shared/development/nodejs$basedir
andrepadez@theLookingGlass:nodejs$
```

from now, every time i change to a forward directory, i would get the prompts:

```
andrepadez@theLookingGlass:nodejs$cd project1
andrepadez@theLookingGlass:nodejs/project1$cd static
andrepadez@theLookingGlass:nodejs/project1/static$cd ..
andrepadez@theLookingGlass:nodejs/project1$ ...
```

(i really don't care what happens if i go back to folders behind my base directory)

Is there a way to create such a command?
I have found something close, but it always shows only the current directory:

```
alias basedir="export PS1='\u@\h:\W$ '"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

In your home directory, there is a hidden file (starting with .) named `.bashrc`.  This file is run whenever you login, and sets things like the prompt (environment variable `PS1`), and `alias`es.  The `PS1` variable is set in several places, depending upon the type of terminal you are running -- change them all, or just the one you are using.  The existing `PS1` setup has several codes which get expanded into things like the current working directory path (the `\w`).  Edit the `.bashrc` file (you own it, so no sudo needed).
Change the `\w` wherever the `PS1 being set to:

```
${PWD#$BASE}
```

To set the alias `BASE`, you can add it to the section `# some more ls aliases` in the `.bashrc` file.  Its value is just the value of the `PWD` variable, so

```
export BASE="$PWD"
```

(The quotes would handle the oddities like spaces in directory names).

Comment: I'm sorry, i am a n00b in linux bash. Can you please be more specific about the steps to be taken? thanks

Comment: @AndréAlçadaPadez In case you didn't get this resolved already: can you be more specific about what you didn't understand or couldn't do? ubfan1's answer seems fairly complete to me.